# javascript Regex : how split CSV file?

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

I am trying to split a CSV file by line using a regex

```
arr = s.split(/\r\n/g);
```

it works correctly except when there is a \r\n inside the text delimiter ("...")

the CSV file looks like :

```
Nom;Prenom;Adresse;CP;Ville
DUPONT;Albert;"immeuble Future
3 rue de la source
";75000;PARIS
MARTIN;Etienne;"23 rue des lilas
Cité Aubépine
Quartier Saint Laurent";75000;PARIS
```

what I want is to cut with each \r\n except those inside the delimiters

any idea ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code who make the same, but without regex :

```
function nbTextDelimiter(s) {
  var a = s.match(/\"/gi);
  return a? a.length : 0; 
}

var arr = st.split(/\r\n/g), arrOut=[], c=0;

for(var i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++){
  var n = nbTextDelimiter(arr[i]);
  if(!c){
    arrOut.push(arr[i]);  
    if(n%2==1){ c=!c }
  } else {
    arrOut[arrOut.length-1]+=arr[i];
    if(n%2==1){ c=!c }  
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions is not suited for this task. Use CSV parser for this task. For instance this parser http://papaparse.com/ looks good.